# How to add a duplicate dropdown with different results

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with a set of drop-downs. Changing those drop-downs generates a small snippet of code corresponding to the selection.

---

The sample below is a how all bindings have been written at the moment.

```js
jQuery('#one').on('change', function(event){
 var selectedElement = $(this).find('option:selected');
  jQuery('#code-section').text("You have selected " + selectedElement.text());
});
```

```css
.code-section {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block" class="block-one">
  <select name="one" id="one">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>  
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>

 <div class="code-section" id="code-section">
   //This is the code snippet area
 </div>
</div>
```

---

I now have to add another set to the same page. It will behave exactly like the first set but will generate a different kind of snippet.

[image]

All the javascript bindings for the 1st set are coupled with element ids. How do I add another dropdown with its own bindings with minimal duplication of code?

---

Some of the ways I have been trying are:

1. **Move all bindings from ids to classes** - The issues with this method is that almost all operations have been done using absolute ids and corresponding attributes of those element. This will require a massive rewrite of all the JS.
2. **Rewrite the Javascript to make it operate on parameters instead of direct bindings** - This theoretically would be the right approach but will require a lot of time which is something I cannot afford at the moment.
3. **Duplicate both markup and JS for the dropdown and change all ids in the copy** - Not ideal but will the get the job done.

Is there is any other way to look at this?

Comment: Explaining why you are down voting this question will help me frame this question better

Comment: I think it is because you haven't provided the code that you have tried, meaning we can't re-produce your problem